# Loading Google +1 script dynamically with jQuery.getScript()

Tags: jquery, google-plus, getscript

i want to load google +1 button only when needed,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

so i was thinking of using `jQuery.getScript()` to do so like:

```
$.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', function(data, textStatus){});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

but how can i pass the `parsetags: 'explicit'` param ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, dont bother,
i found a solution:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js",
  dataType: "script",
  parameters: { parsetags: "explicit" }, 
  success: function () { gapi.plusone.go();  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a global variable as follows, then load the g+ script:

`window['___gcfg'] = { parsetags: 'explicit' };`

Comment: could you explain what it does?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. I thought you were looking for a way to pass the parameter `parsetags: 'explicit'` to load/parse the g+ button only when needed. The way explained above (setting parameters in $.ajax) didn't work for me. But if you set the global variable before laoding the g+ js file as explained in my posting, `plusone.js` won't parse your dom tree until you tell it to do so.

Comment: at the time (two years ago) i was looking to load the script on demand and not load it with the rest of the page.

Comment: ok so that is exactly what it does. :) I needed it for myself a couple of weeks ago.